# what does handle() in android handlers

Tags: android, handler

I am working on an Android project that works well, and it uses `Handler` methods. But, I can't find this particular method in any tutorials or documentation.

The `Handler` method looks like this:

```
    private Handler OnName = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handle() {
        //do some stuff that needs it's own thread
        finish();
    }
};
```

It is overwriting the `handle()` method, I am not finding it in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Am I looking in the wrong place, or what is this for?
Can someone a short explanation or a good link of when `handle()`
triggers?

Comment: Are you sure that they are using `android.os.Handler`, and not some subclass with the same name?

Comment: How could I be this stupid, I didn't check the imports. You are right, its not the android.os.Handler but a subclass. Can you make your comment an answer, so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am working on an android project where previous coders used Handlers

More importantly, the previous coders didn't use a distinct class name, causing confusion for others encountering the code base.

Please slap the previous coders with a trout for me.

> Am I looking in the wrong place, or what is this for?

As you discovered, this isn't `android.os.Handler`, but something else. My guess is that it is a subclass of `android.os.Handler`, where (for whatever reason) they are ignoring the `Message` normally delivered to `handleMessage()`.

Comment: I wish this was the only problem with this project. And I would love to slap them :D Thanks again.